# Getting very high fps for video stream captured and stored using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame-rate

I've written a small python code, which captures video stream from the webcam, and writes it into an output file.

I've put a sleep of 50 ms, and specified a fps of 20.0 in the VideoWriter as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import threading
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from io import StringIO,BytesIO
import time
import datetime

capture=None
out=None

class CamHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.endswith('.mjpg'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()
            while True:
                try:
                    rc,img = capture.read()
                    if not rc:
                        continue
                    #Get the timestamp on the frame
                    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
                    ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
                    cv2.putText(img, ts, (10, img.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
                    #Store the frame into the output file
                    out.write(img)
                    #Some processing before sending the frame to webserver
                    imgRGB=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    jpg = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
                    tmpFile = BytesIO()
                    jpg.save(tmpFile,'JPEG')
                    self.wfile.write("--jpgboundary".encode())
                    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-length',str(tmpFile.getbuffer().nbytes))
                    self.end_headers()
                    jpg.save(self.wfile,'JPEG')
                    time.sleep(0.05)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
            return
        if self.path.endswith('.html'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('<html><head></head><body>'.encode())
            self.wfile.write('<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/cam.mjpg"/>'.encode())
            self.wfile.write('</body></html>'.encode())
            return


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

def main():
    global capture
    global out
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

    global img
    try:
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), CamHandler)
        print( "server started")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        capture.release()
        server.socket.close()
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works fine, and I'm able to get the video saved. However, the fps as seen in property of the video is 600.0 (30X what I set!!)

```
$ mediainfo output.avi 
General
Complete name                            : output.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 4.95 MiB
Duration                                 : 17s 252ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 408 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf58.3.100

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L1
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 17s 252ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 290 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 600.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.012
Stream size                              : 4.71 MiB (95%)
Writing library                          : Lavc58.6.103
```

I'm pretty sure my code looks alright, do let me know if there are any obvious mistakes. In case it matters, I'm using an ubuntu OS, Asus X553M laptop with inbuilt webcam to run the above.

EDIT 1:
I'm using python3, if that matters

EDIT 2:
Using MJPG codec did solve the problem, (thanks @api55) so can someone tell me why XVID would give the incorrect fps?

Is it possible that XVID codec incorrectly writes the fps property, while the video is actually correctly coded in 20 fps?

Comment: Are you sure it's not breaking out of your try before it hits your delay?

Comment: Have you tried with a different FPS, e.g. 15, 25? do you get the same result? Have you tried with another fourcc? Have you tried with a the same code but with a static image (let say in a loop of 100 ) instead of getting it with your process?

Comment: I think only `fps` parameter in `cv2.VideoWriter` set the video `FPS` property, while the  `sleep` has no effects on the video `FPS` property. I test the code, and the line is `Frame rate                               : 20.000 fps`

Comment: @Silencer: Can you please let me know the exact piece of code? I'm using python3 fyi.

Comment: Just curious, is it possible that the webcam fps is causing something like this?

Comment: GPPK : I'm absolutely sure its not breaking out. @api55: Tried with fps 30, same result. However, using MJPG did change fps to what I wanted! Pretty strange huh? How do you explain that?

Comment: @Jamboree I think only this line `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))` has effect on the `FPS` property. I test your original code, then use `mediainfo output.avi` to get the info, the FPS line is what I posted  `Frame rate : 20.000 fps`, different with your result. I don't think webcam fps has effect on it. Such as, when you save the pictures (without FPS info) into  video, the fps is decided by the `fps parameter`.

Comment: @Silencer The problem got fixed on using MJPG, strange right?

Comment: @Jamboree i just gave you a list of things that I would test to find the exact problem. It could be that the codec does not take the property of opencv correctly.

Comment: @api55 Ok. BTW, any clue why my video is running far faster than it should?

Comment: how do you check the actual fps of the video?

Comment: of course, if you capture a frame every 50 ms + time to process let's say 60 ms in total that is roughly 16 -17 fps then you set 25 FPS in your video, that means that it will play almost 2 seconds of video in 1 second... then you get this looks like faster feeling. BTW even with 50 ms and immediate saving, it will be around 20 fps. You need to make your sleep like `40ms - TimeLapseFromCurrentFrame`. 40 ms per frame is 25 fps, take the time from your last image take, and see what is left and sleep unti it reaches 40 ms, then you take another one

Answer (score 0):

You getting frames every 50 ms + processing time, but writing them to video with delay 50ms, so they will be played with higher speed with ratio=(50+processing time)/ 50ms.

Comment: can you elaborate on how I'm writing video with delay 20ms?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, confused ms and fps. I fixed the answer. I think processing time is relatively long.

Comment: just remove the sleep. Capturing will automatically wait until a new frame is available.

Comment: easy to test whether this is the problem: Capture N images to an array/list/buffer without any processing/encoding/sleep and write them to video file  afterwards. Just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have this recipe, it's pretty similar to what Andrey answered. The fps gets pretty close to what's expected.

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(capture) # 0 | filepath
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
period = 1000 / fps

while cap.isOpened():
    start = time.time()

    success, frame = cap.read()
    if not success:
        if capture:
            break  # video
        continue  # cam

    # processing steps

    cv2.imshow('video (ESC to quit)', frame)
    processing_time = (time.time() - start) * 1000
    wait_ms = period - processing_time if period > processing_time else period
    if cv2.waitKey(int(wait_ms)) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
    end = (time.time() - start)
    print(f'FPS: {1.0 / end:.2f} (expected {fps:.2f})\r', end='')
```